# Branch IO not Redirecting in some Browsers in Android

Tags: android, branch.io

I am using branch io SDK in Android. However, I am facing issues in redirection. The link gets redirected to my app whenever it is clicked from Facebook. However, it is not redirected to my app whenever it is clicked from a browser. This occurs randomly. In some devices, it redirects to the app from the default browser but not from any other browser. In other devices, it redirects the app only from Chrome and not any other browser.

EDIT:

It redirets to the app every time from the Facebook app.

I have the following code with me :

Code in Android Manifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey"
            android:value="key_live_my_key"     />
```

This is how I generate the link:

```
BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject = new BranchUniversalObject()
                .setCanonicalIdentifier("item/12345")
                .setTitle("My Content Title")
                .setContentDescription("My Content Description");

        LinkProperties linkProperties = new LinkProperties()
                .setChannel("sms")
                .setFeature("invite")
                .addControlParameter("My id", Parameter);
```

Comment: Alex with Branch.io here: just to check before we debug further, have you been all the way through our [SDK integration guide](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/) and [app links configuration doc](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/guide/android/)? Specifically, what do your `intents` for [URI schemes](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/#register-a-uri-scheme) and [HTTPS links](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/guide/android/#add-intent-filter-to-manifest) look like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did integrate the sdk properly and created app links as well. I hadn't integrated app links earlier. Yet, the app links work properly except for Twitter app. My links are not yet redirecting to my app via all browsers. It's sort of random. I get redirected through a different browser on a different Android version.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. There was a setting in my dashboard which says always try to open app, I clicked on it and now everything is working fine. Thanks a lot for your assistance.